# Using createContextualFragment with JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I am trying to include a "contextual component" in JSX, what am I doing wrong?

Note that I need the scripts to run, so dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not an option. Also I'd like to build a Function Component for use with hooks.

```
export default function ContextualComponent() {

    const node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment("<div>My html and scripts</div>");

    return (
      <div>{node}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Probably don't want to tag it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is it's specifically not an option ;)

Comment: lol I was thinking that people who know about dangerouslySetInnerHTML are familiar with the matter :-)

Comment: [DocumentFragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) require the use of `appendChild` to append nodes into the real document tree. How that works with React is a great question... I suspect you will need to escape React and use vanilla js here

Comment: @Dominik I was afraid of that. I am wondering if a React ref could help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any direct interaction with the DOM, you need a React ref. What you want can be implemented with `useRef` and `useEffect`:

```js
const ContextualComponent = ({ html }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = ref;

    const documentFragment = document
      .createRange()
      .createContextualFragment(html);

    current.appendChild(documentFragment);

    return () => {
      current.textContent = "";
    };
  }, [html]);

  return <div ref={ref} />;
};
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-dom-exec-scripts-48u0k)

Comment: Splendid! As I commented above, I tried ref but couldn't figure out the proper implementation. Thanks.